# Same Assembly Version in multiple mixed .NET projects (same solution)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, assemblyinfo

I've got a problem with setting up one "Shared" assembly info in my solution. I need one place to change assembly version for every project in the solution (currently > 25 project). 
The problem is, that the solution contains C# projects as well as VB.NET projects - because of that, I am not able to create ONE file with assembly version (I cannot include C# files in VB.NET project and vice versa...)

Is there any way to solve the problem ?

Comment: It's not exactly straightforward but you can use text transformations: prepare a T4 template with relevant settings and code to generate both `SharedAssemblyInfo.cs` and `SharedAssemblyInfo.vb` in pre-build.

Comment: at the moment, i think it's the best possible solution - iam going to try this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Shared Assembly Info using file linking.

Here is a nice article from Ashish Jain:
https://weblogs.asp.net/ashishnjain/sharing-assembly-version-across-projects-in-a-solution

If the VB Project does not allow linking with the SharesAssemblyInfo.cs then we could create another library with SharedAssemblyInfo.vb.

If duplication is not wished for then a library called SharedAssemblyInfo can be created in C#/VB with public properties. These public properties could then we referred to in both C# and VB projects in their respective AssemblyInfo.cs files

Comment: From question: _"...solution contains C# projects as well as VB.NET projects...I cannot include C# files in VB.NET project and vice versa..."_

Comment: One could create one SharedAssemblyInfo.vb and one SharedAssemblyInfo.cs. We have duplication but atleast reduced.

Comment: OP is aware of that, he was asking how to have just one

Comment: If i cannot reduce this to just one file, then i just make yet another complication in the project (younger devs have to know that they've to edit the two files - it's not intuitive)

Comment: If duplication is not wished for then a library called SharedAssemblyInfo can be created in C#/VB with public properties. These public properties could then we referred to in both C# and VB projects in their respective AssemblyInfo.cs files